# FTPS ClickOnce publish in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, security, ftp, clickonce, ftps

We are using Visual Studio 2019 to publish WPF applications with ClickOnce. We use a FTP server to deploy our apps. It seems that Visual Studio can only push files using FTP and cannot use FTPS (explicit or implicit), which is an security issue for us.

Using a FTPS (implicit) URL (like `ftps://myftpsserver.com:990`), we get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to 'ftps://myftpsserver.com/MyApp:990/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'ftps://myftpsserver.com/MyApp:990'.  Can't connect to 'myftpsserver.com'. Check the server name and proxy settings. If the settings are correct, the server may be temporarily unavailable.
```

I don't think it comes from our server because we are able to use FTPS (explicit or implicit) with other clients like FileZilla. FTPS seems supported for Web App deployment in Visual Studio 2019:

- [FTPS publish in Visual Studio fails, results in "Secure connection was closed by the remote connection end."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052415/ftps-publish-in-visual-studio-fails-results-in-secure-connection-was-closed-by)
- https://fynydd.com/blog/publish-a-site-in-visual-studio-using-implicit-ftp-over-tls/

But I did not found any documentation saying that it is supported for ClickOnce deployment. The only alternative I see for now is publishing on a local folder and pushing it on our deployment server using another FTP client like winscp (as mentioned here: [Publishing in Visual Studio with FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669515/publishing-in-visual-studio-with-ftp)).

My two questions:

- Is there any official documentation about ClickOnce deployment over FTPS to know if it is supported or not?
- Is there a better alternative than doing a local publish and using another FTP client?

Comment: According to your error message, I suggest you follow this document https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/topic/-cannot-connect-to-the-ftp-server-error-message-when-you-access-an-ftp-site-966a0c39-dd67-20cd-b3dd-159a096761e8 first to rule out the cause due to server error and turn off the firewall.